# How to invoke a function stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want invoke the below ajaxSend function with parameter.But getting Illegal invocation error

```
var req = Ajax.getXMLHttpRequest();//raw xhr
var ajaxSend = req.send;
req.send = function (param) {
    req.setRequestHeader('aaa','bbb');
    eval(ajaxSend(param));
}
return req;
```

Comment: `ajaxSend(parameter)`

Comment: Why the eval? Just `ajaxSend(param)` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval` like that means that you first call the function, then call `eval` using the return value from the function. You shouldn't use `eval` at all, though.

You are already calling the function (even if you then have an `eval` around it), but it doesn't work to call the function that way.

When you get the function reference and assign it to the variable, it's no longer attached to the object. When you call it, it will have the global object (`window`) as context, not the `req` object.

Use the `call` method to specify the context when you call the function:

```
ajaxSend.call(req, param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried eval("ajaxSend(param)"); ?